# Angular2: How to pass a variable from an observable to another function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

The code below obviously does not work.  I am trying to pass a variable that was retrieved from the rxjs observable function to another function.  However, I  have no idea how to do that and I can't find a suitable example.

So for example the code below, the `getUserName()` successfully retrieves the this.username from the JSON.  However, I have no idea on how to pass this to the  getUserInfo() function.

I always get undefined.

```
import {Component, OnInit, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Post} from './Post';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  username: any; 

  constructor(private http: Http) {}


getUserName(){
 this.http.get("http://localhost:1337/user").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
             data =>  this.username = data.username,
            err => console.log(err))
}

getUserInfo(){
   console.log(this.username);
}






}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be not a direct answer to your question, maybe it helps non-the-less,
I'm assuming that you want to use the user-data somewhere in a component and most likely a template - in that case it is usually helpful to use a `BehaviorSubject` to store and access the fetched data, you could do it like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    userData$ = new BehaviorSubject<IUserData>();

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.userData$
            .subscribe(data => doSomeStuffWheneverUserDataUpdates(data));
    }

    fetchUserData(){
        this.http.get("http://localhost:1337/user")
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                data => this.userData$.next(data),
                err => console.log(err)
            );
    }
}
```

...and somewhere in your component you could use:

```
class MyComponent {
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        userService.fetchUserData();

        // optionally you could subscribe here to
        // userService.userData$ to do some action whenever
        // the userData updates, just don't forget to
        // unsubscribe when the component is destroyed
    }
}
```

...and in the template:

```
<div>UserName: {{(userService.userData$ | async)?.username}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined because the getUserInfo() function is being called before the subscription to the JSON is being implemented.

You could add a parameter to getUserInfo(data) and then in the getUserName() you could add this line of code -> this.getUserInfo(data);

After that you should see the console.log displaying the information.